# Bar How can we customize the with of a Tab widget from TabBar widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, iso

I am makeing a clone of whatsapp. So i need to customize the Tab width as the camera icon width is less than other in whatsapp.
[image]

I want to design this like:
[image]

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that you’ve tried so far and image what are you trying to archive?

Comment: i have added the snippet so far i want to resize the camera icon width,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what you want to achieve. You need to set the `isScrollable: true` if you want tabs of different sizes. Additionally, to take full spacing controls we will also set the `labelPadding` to zero. To render the child with different widths we will simply use the screen size to determine the size.

```
          TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            controller: tabController,
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            tabs: [1, 2, 3, 4].map((e) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: (e == 1 ? 0.1 : 0.3) * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Tab(
                  iconMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  child: Text(
                    e.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          )
```

This code will generate the output you are expecting. You can design the tabs accordingly.

Comment: Thanks man, this works as i expected to.

Comment: Welcome, keep coding!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is working for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `isScrollable: true` and provide width based on your need.

```dart
TabBar(
  isScrollable: true,
  tabs: [SizedBox(width:.)...],)
```

Comment: i tried this was but its not working propurly

Comment: Consider including the issue reproducible snippet and what went wrong.